# How to force Word to find every column int the Excel datasource using mail merge

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, mail-merge

I have the following Excel table as data source containg around 20 rows:

[image]

When I open the Word file that uses that Excel, it asks if I want to use the query again (it is set to query it via Excel DDE):

[image]

When I say yes, it usually fails:

[image]

When I reselect the datasource (after 500 times, again), it opens the file:

[image]

I usually chose the whole table as datasource:

[image]

When I use the mail merge function, it shows that **only 1 field** is contained in the source Excel file and can't find the rest:

[image]

No Word, it contains all the column headers.

How can I force Word to read all the data source and not only the first column?

Comment: It's choking on something.  Run some tests.  Delete all the columns except the first and then duplicate it so you have 2 rename the second and see if it now see 2 columns or still just 1.  If 2 figure out by process of elimination what is tripping it up.

Comment: @BlindSpots I will test it. I just can't get my head around that a 20+ years old feature (that is probably quite well tested) can't process a small sheet with 100 cells in it. Like my car has a steering wheel that sometimes just does not turn the wheels - yeah, it works in 90% of the cases yet I don't really consider it generally working.

Comment: The DDE connection method has been "deprecated" for about 20 years. In some versions of Office, Microsoft has turned off the ability to use it altogether because of known security risks and reliability problems. (Re-)Connection has become more difficult over time. Using the current version of Office, I see similar problems except that I do not see only one field. It may help to open the .xls in Excel before opening the Word Mail Merge Main document.

Comment: If possible, change to using the default method (OLE DB, which Word chooses automatically for a new connection). The main reasons people resist change (other than "why should I?") are that OLE DB can't connect to .xls files that were password-protected, and DDE tends to return the data in the same format that you actually see in the worksheet, whereas OLEDB will do things like strip leading zeroes and make other formatting changes.